# SwiftUI Infinite Subview Hierarchy and Breadcrumbs

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, swiftui, breadcrumbs

what I am trying to achieve is creating a hierarchical view. I understand that iOS simply doesn't like to use breadcrumbs but I need to navigate from a main view in to deeper subviews. they need to be nested and infinite.

you can see what I've done so far in the code and gif below. As I'm a beginner developer I'm not sure if this is the right way to achieve this kind of structure (infinite sub-views nested inside sub-views). Also when I navigate back in views, added buttons(struct A) disappears. What seems to be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

[code in action gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imRau.gif)

```
import SwiftUI

struct A: View, Identifiable {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var documentB: classB
    
    var id: Int
    var text: String
    var destinationLink: B?
    
    var body: some View {
            NavigationLink(destination: self.destinationLink) {
                VStack{
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 35, height:25)
                        .background(Color.red)
                    Text("\(text)")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct B: View, Identifiable {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var documentB: classB
    @State var arrayA: [A] = []
    
    var id: Int
    var text: String
    var mainText: String = "Placeholder"
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                ForEach(arrayA){ item in
                    item
                }
                Spacer()

                Button(action: {
                    let newB = B(id:self.documentB.arrayB.count+1, text:"B \(self.documentB.arrayB.count+1)")
                    self.documentB.arrayB.append(newB)
                    self.arrayA.append(A(id:self.arrayA.count+1, text:"AA \(self.arrayA.count+1)", destinationLink: newB))
                }) {
                    Text("Add A \(self.arrayA.count), B Count: \(self.documentB.arrayB.count)")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(text)
        }
    }
}

class classB: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var arrayB: [B] = [B(id:1, text:"MainView")]
    
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var documentB = classB()

    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                documentB.arrayB[0]
            }
            .environmentObject(documentB)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move `NavigationView` into `ContentView`, because the only one is needed on one view hierarchy, so

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var documentB = classB()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {    // << move it here from B
            VStack {
                documentB.arrayB[0]
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(documentB)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually what's bothering me more is if this is the right structure for infinite sub-views? Because items(structA) are disappearing after I go back to main view.

Comment: Well, because you do this with views, but if you'd do this with model, which kept persistent and construct views based on model, then all would be persistent.... but that's different story.